# can i add contents to insert in a List<ContentValues> and then pass it to another function to insert in SQLite DB?

Tags: android, json, sqlite

I have a doubt.

I am creating an simple app which uses online and offline DB. I am implementing syncing operation using JSON format data.
I am accessing data from online DB using JSON.

my doubt is can i add contents to insert in a List and then pass it to another function to insert in SQLite DB?

I have tried this code

```
    for(int i=1;i<=rowCount;i++)
     {
    rows=rowObject.getString(i+"");
    object=new JSONObject(rows);

    /* code to put extracted values to cv
    cv.put("colomn name","value");
   .*/

    //List<ContentValues> rowData=null; this is rowData
     rowData.add(cv);
    }
```

When inserting as a list of content values its nserting double size of actual number of elemets. it wont delete the values already in table..

```
db.execSQL("DELETE FROM "+TABLE_NAME_MENU);// this is deletion code.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
rowData.add(cv)
```

Is that code correct?? I see you loop through using the

```
object=new JSONObject(rows);
```

so, how it will be if you using

```
rowData.add(object)
```

Comment: List<ContentValues> rowData;

I am adding the content of object (object=new JSONObject(rows); ) to a contentvalue object like cvObj.put("colomn name","value");

Comment: Try using the ArrayList, it can handle better for your case